Is there such a thing as "function attribute correctness"?
Ok so C23 adds function attributes to the language but I'm not sure if anyone actually considered how they are supposed to be used. Consider this example:
[[deprecated]] int foo () { return 0; }
[[nodiscard]]  int bar () { return 0; }

int main()
{
  typedef int foo_t ();
  foo_t* fp1;
  foo_t* fp2;
  foo_t* fp3;

  fp1 = foo;
  fp2 = fp1;
  fp3 = bar;
  fp1();
  fp2();
  fp3();
}

Some things of note here:

It is not possible for me to specify an attribute in the typedef because apparently attributes are not attached to the type.
The only warning I get in gcc or clang for this entire program is during fp1 = foo; assignment. foo is deprecated.
I do not get a warning when assigning fp1 to fp2.
I do not get a warning when calling a deprecated function through fp1 or fp2.
I do not get a warning when calling fp3 but ignore/discard the result.

Furthermore, there appears to be no check between function declarations and definitions. This compiles cleanly:
[[unsequenced]] int foo ();
[[nodiscard]]   int foo ();
[[deprecated]]  int foo () { return 0; }

Why would I ever want a compiler to allow such nonsense?
Function attributes are not attached to the type, so how can we get "function attribute correctness" and making them work as intended? Or are they just plain underspecified/broken, added to the language at a whim, to be fixed at a later point when someone can be bothered to actually examine the consequences of them?
Am I missing something here?

Twelve years too late to complain, since the same can be said of the _Noreturn keyword.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah but that was just an oddball feature for manual optimization purposes. The purpose of the new attributes isn't just optimization, but program safety. Supposedly.

I feel old for agreeing and still using __attribute__((deprecated))  foo_t* fp1; and __attribute__((warn_unused_result)) foo_t *fp3;

Some attributes can be attached to typedef but the attribute applies to the typedef name rather than the type name.

Re “Furthermore, there appears to be no check between function declarations and definitions”: Draft N3096 says “A name or entity declared without the deprecated attribute can later be redeclared with the attribute and vice versa. An entity is considered marked with the attribute after the first declaration that marks it” and there is similar text for some other attributes (I did not check them). So this (a) appears intentional and (b) can be specified by the standard independently for each attribute. One use of it would be that a programmer wishes to be warned…

… about using a particular function or ignoring a return value but does not want to change the system or third-party header. The behavior specified by the standard allows them to redeclare the function to add the desired attribute without modifying the header.

Re “I do not get a warning when assigning fp1 to fp2”: There is no need for that since a warning was already given for referring to a deprecated function when assigning to fp1. The specification for deprecated is such that no program that refers to a deprecated function will compile without a diagnostic (when the compiler follows recommended practice). The lack of a warning for ignoring a nodiscard result is more troubling, as there bad code can escape warning.

@EricPostpischil "An entity is considered marked with the attribute after the first declaration that marks it" So by design, in case of multiple declarations as in my example, the first translation unit that happens to be compiled is the one that gets to apply the attribute? What if there are conflicting attributes, does it keep appending more of them or do they overwrite each other? What if the attribute was placed on the function definition only, but the definition is in another translation unit than the caller?

Attributes do not span translation units.

@EricPostpischil That sounds dangerous. So if someone adds an attribute to a function definition with internal linkage, that attribute will just dissolve in thin air when called from a different translation unit. And since the declaration need not match the definition, there's no safety.
